# Intellij -server flag

Tags: intellij-idea

I've seen suggestions to improve the performance of intellij putting the flag -server on idea.exe.vmoptions (or idea64.exe.vmoptions), what is the benefit of using -server flag on intellij 14 ?

How can I decide if enable this flag?

Answer (score 1):

These .vmoptions files specify options for the JVM on which IDEA runs.
So for the -server parameter the official Java documentation states that:

> Selects the Java HotSpot Server VM

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

and

> In general, the server VM starts up more slowly than the client VM, but over time runs more quickly.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html

However, it is explicitly mentioned that:

> The 64-bit version of the JDK supports only the Server VM, so in that case the option is implicit.

In other words when using the "server" flag, IDEA may start up more slowly, but may perform better. However specifying it makes sense only if you're using a 32-bit java to run IDEA.

Note that idea.sh or idea.bat have logic in them which tries first to find 64 bit java on the machine and if such is not found, tries to locate 32-bit one. If you're starting it on Windows with idea.exe, always 32 bit java will be used. If you're starting it on Windows with idea64.exe, always 64 bit java will be used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but is there any benefit of using the -server flag in intellij on a machine of 64bits? How can I decide if enable this flag?